# Failed to start Kernel [Errorno 2] Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, miniconda

I am trying to run jupyter notebook on my system from the terminal (MacOS Catalina)

I have recently done a fresh install of python and anaconda. Miniconda was previously on my machine but I removed it before installing anaconda. However, when running notebook, I get the following error in my browser:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1703, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 308, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 215, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/sumeet/miniconda3/bin/python'
```

This happens no matter what virtual conda environment I run from. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is as follows:

Run the command:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Rename the directory the python3 kernel points too.
Run jupyter notebook

```
Use jupyter kernelspec uninstall 'oldPython'
```

All done!